# Como sacar un datediff con decimales?

Tags: sql

Estoy buscando una manera de como convertir un resultado de un datediff a decimal.
Tengo el siguiente query:

```
Tiempo_Atencion = CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(mi,  FechaAsignacion  , FechaCierreMedico )) < 5 then ''
                       else   DATEDIFF(mi,  FechaAsignacion  , FechaCierreMedico )/60.0 end
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Error al convertir el tipo
>   de datos varchar a numeric.

Alguien me puede explicar alguna otra manera de resolver mi problema?

Comment: El problema es que FechaAsigancion no es una fecha sino un varchar, y no se puede convertir a fecha de manera implícita. Revisa la función convert, uno de los parámetros es para definir el formato de fecha.

Comment: como asi?
Tiempo_Atencion = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, convert(int, FechaAsignacion)  , convert(int,FechaCierreMedico) ) < 5 THEN '' 
                      ELSE DATEDIFF(mi,  convert(int, FechaAsignacion)    , convert(int,FechaCierreMedico ))/60.0 END,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por todo ya me salio la respuesta,

```
Tiempo_Atencion = CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(mi,  FechaAsignacion  , FechaCierreMedico )) < 5 then 0.0
                       else   DATEDIFF(mi,  FechaAsignacion  , FechaCierreMedico )/60.0 end
```

la respuesta es no poner `''` ya que los vacio considera un `varchar` y es mejor poner `0.0` o `null` para considerar `numeric`

Answer (score 0):

Usa el CAST o CONVERT el que mas te convenga para convertir el resultado del DATEDIFF en Decimal

```
CASE WHEN CAST(DATEDIFF(mi,  FechaAsignacion  , FechaCierreMedico ) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) < 5 THEN '' 
ELSE CAST(DATEDIFF(mi,  FechaAsignacion  , FechaCierreMedico ) AS DECIMAL(10,2))/60.0 END
```

SALUDOS

Comment: #TheVicShow igual sal el errror de :Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a numeric.